# Python Dash Framework Networking

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm learning Dash library for creating dashboards. I'm in Dash Tutorial - Part 1: App Layout

When i run my app.py file in cmd. It shows: *Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)*. Then i can open app in my web brower at the **SAME** computer using url it give me.

But it doesn't work when i open it in other computer's browser using same URL.

I thought my app using dash as a server. So when the program is running anyone can open it in their own computer browser. But appearently it's not the case.

I want to create a web application so that when i run anyone can open. But i'm not familiar with computer networking at all. Is this a proxy server problem? What can i do?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfKzi.png)

Comment: I have to give you the link for the app i'm trying to run:

https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started

Any of the app. For example run python app.py for "Generating HTML with Dash" on my own browser. Pop up 

$ python app.py
...Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

But when i run in other computer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to **deploy** your web app. [This](https://www.fullstackpython.com/deployment.html) guide of Full Stack Python gives a great overview of the deployment process with plenty of resources.

To quote the author:

> The deployer needs to provision one or more servers with a Linux distribution. System packages, a web server, WSGI server, database and the Python environment are then installed. Finally the application can be pulled from source and installed in the environment.

Cloud services (Azure, AWS, Google Cloud) make the deployment process really easy and cheap these days. They all provide sep-by-step guides on how to deploy your web-app.

Answer (score 0):

if youre on windows, run ipconfig, and use the IPv4 Address (i.e. 172.129.193.1). To access on another computer, type in the address bar the `ip-address:port`, e.g. http://172.129.193.1:8050. This is limited to your own network (i.e. another computer connected by LAN/wifi).

To access externally, anywhere in the internet, you need to find a web host server, and upload your code onto it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Like you said i need a web host server. 

I figured out the problem. It's because my computer running as a local host server. So only i can see. I can configue in a way that everyone else on my network can see. Just do app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0'). Something about unmask all the ipv4 addresses.

Comment: Maybe you also have to reconfigure your firewall and allow local tcp traffic on port 8050.